# First column freezed while scrolling horizontally and all tds should be dragable in Table using jQuery

Tags: css

I want to freeze first column while scrolling horizontally and I want
to assign one td to another td. 1 problem- while td assigning time if

I am moving just little bit to td it is not coming to its old place.
For that I need any event to be occur so that I can refresh the page.

2 problem- if I freeze first column then I cannot move td of first column.

```
 jsfiddle.net/kuldeep9211/90chfhwo/7/
```

Please help.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kuldeep9211/90chfhwo/7/

Comment: Basic rule of StackOverflow: Show us what you have done so far

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow ! Where is your code ?

Comment: code is in this link -- http://jsfiddle.net/kuldeep9211/90chfhwo/7/